# electron, сборка под windows

Tags: windows, macos, electron

Можно ли на macos собрать файл .exe, и если да то как? Буду признателен. Я пробовал с помощью electron-forge, там не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/)

```
{
  "name": "PRO-CODE",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "main": "app/dist/main/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn workspace main build",
    "electron-build": "yarn build && electron-builder",
    "build:app": "yarn electron-build --dir",
    "build:all": "yarn electron-build build -mwl",
    "build:mac": "yarn electron-build build --mac",
    "build:linux": "yarn electron-build build --linux",
    "build:windows": "yarn electron-build build --windows --x64"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.5",
    "electron-builder": "^22.10.5"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "build": {
    "appId": "org.dev.PRO-CODE",
    "productName": "PRO-CODE",
    "artifactName": "${productName}.${ext}",
    "directories": {
      "output": "release"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/**/*"
    ],
    "mac": {
      "icon": "resources/icons/icon.icns"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "portable"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb",
        "AppImage"
      ],
      "category": "Development"
    }
  }
}
```